# SwiftUI List with Tow Functions in Edit Mode

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I try to get two functions for list rows when the view became in edit mode as shown in the photo bellow one section for select and other section for deleting, I already separate them into two section in my code any try many things but it's not work.

[image]

And this is my code, and example for a section

```
     var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List(selection: $selection) {
                if isEditMode || !groupData.rowsGroup[0].filter({$0.isOnMain}).isEmpty {
                    firstSection
                }
                
                if !sortedFavoriteLists.isEmpty {
                    favoriteSection
                }
                
                if isEditMode || !groupData.rowsGroup[1].filter({$0.isOnMain}).isEmpty {
                    secondSection
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        }
    }

// This is the section and each section is "ForEach" View

        private var firstSection: some View {
        Section {
            ForEach(firstSectionData, content: MainMenuRowView.init)
                .onMove { indices, newOffset in
                    groupData.rowsGroup[0].move(fromOffsets: indices, toOffset: newOffset)
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried at least?

Comment: I post the code

Answer (score 0):

One problem solved by embed everything inside "Form", but know when I activate edit mode the Lise select not appear, anyone have an answer for how to activate the selection circle in the list???

This is example code

```
 NavigationView{
            Form{
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                    }.onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                        //
                    })
                }

                
                Section{
                    ForEach(data, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        //
                    })
                    .onMove(perform: { indices, newOffset in
                        //
                    })
                    
                }

            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tilte")
                .navigationBarTitle("Main Menu", displayMode: .inline)
                .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        EditButton()
                    }
                })
        }
```

And this is how its look

[image]